# Cakephp model linking query problems

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

This are my models:

```
User hasmany Photos

Photo belongto User
```

Really simple One to many relation.

In the controller i would like to see all the Photos of one User.

```
$this->User->id = $id
$this->User->Photos->read()
```

That not working and i know that if i use

```
$cond=array(
    'conditions' => array('UserId =' => $id),
    'recursive' => -1 
    );
$relationsFrom = $this->User->Photos->find('all', $cond);
```

Can I do this query without using find with the conditions?
I give the foreign key when i've linked the models. Why have I to write again? 
I remember that in Ruby on Rails User.Photos give me all the photos of the User.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you pasted all the code correctly? It should be Photo not Photos, and User.id not UserId

Comment: I'm afraid that's just the way Cake works. I'd like to see an explanation for the wonky design, though.

Comment: i'm working with a older db, I can't change the name of tables and fields. By the way with Containable more less i've found a good way to solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `Containable` behavior? It will select the related models for you in the way that you want. It will select the related fields based on your relationships

Comment: thanks man, it's work more less. I have to do 2 queries one for my User and one for the user Photos. The first is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you why it works like that but not why it was *designed* to work like that:

The object `$this->User->Photos` is an instance of the `Photo` model class that has no special reference to the `User` model that references it. You can use `$this->User->Photos` just like you could use `new Photo`.

CakePHP's database layer revolves around methods that take queries encoded as arrays, translate them to SQL, and return the result as arrays of data. It does not build a query object like some ORMs do.